# How to edit Dreamweaver auto close tags?

Tags: html, dreamweaver, html-editor

```
<div class="test"
```

to

```
<div class="test"></div><!-- test out -->
```

Are you able to edit Dreamweaver's auto close tags to something like the example above or can any editor that help you do that?

Comment: While Dreamweaver is a programming tool, this question is about software use, not programming and therefore belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: btw solution might be in a programatic way. :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Dreamweaver can't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Yse ,Dreamweaver can do it that.
Edit>Preferences>Code Hints>select after typing the open tags option

for more information:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/587901